# UWP app with multiple views with different sizes

Tags: windows, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a UWP app. I want to be ale to create new windows from the app, but any subsequent window needs to be a specific smaller size compared to the main window. I don't do anything with regards to sizing the main window and let the OS take care of sizing it for me.

I bring up a new window like this:

```
auto window = CoreApplication::CreateNewView();
window->show();

void NewWindow::show() {
    auto currView = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
    currView->PreferredLaunchViewSize =
        Windows::Foundation::Size(float(options.width), float(options.height));
    currView->PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode::PreferredLaunchViewSize;
    currView->SetPreferredMinSize(Size(20,20));

    Xaml::Window::Current->Activate();

    ApplicationViewSwitcher::TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(
        window_->id(),
        ViewSizePreference::Default,
        window_->parentId(),
        ViewSizePreference::Default);
}
```

When the main window comes up, it comes up just fine. When I click on a  button which gets to this function, the new window comes up in the same size as the main window. I reopen the app, but now the main window shows up in the size I wanted the new window to show up in. Then clicking the button to bring up the new window brings up the new window in the size I wanted it in. So I am a bit confused. Am I setting the sizes the right way? Is there anything else glaringly wrong here?

Comment: PreferredLaunchViewSize controls the view size when the app is **launched**. If you want to resize your secondary views, you can use `TryResizeView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ Raymond Chen said, PreferredLaunchViewSize set the size when the app launches, it will change the size of your main window. And you can use [ApplicationView.TryResizeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryresizeview) method to set the size of new window.

For example:

```
auto parentView = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
auto newView = CoreApplication::CreateNewView();

newView->Dispatcher->RunAsync(Windows::UI::Core::CoreDispatcherPriority::Normal,
        ref new Windows::UI::Core::DispatchedHandler([this,parentView]()
{
    int newViewId = 0;
    Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame^ rootFrame = ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Frame();
    rootFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(MainPage::typeid), nullptr);
    Window::Current->Content = rootFrame;
    // You have to activate the window in order to show it later.
    Window::Current->Activate();

    newViewId = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()->Id;
    IAsyncOperation<bool>^ mytask = ApplicationViewSwitcher::TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(newViewId);
    auto deviceEnumTask = concurrency::create_task(mytask);
    deviceEnumTask.then([this](bool res)
    {
        // set the size of new window
        ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()->TryResizeView(Size(600, 320));
    }); 
}));
```